# how to use SSRS email subscription in asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am using SSRS in my asp.net application. Now I want to use SSRS email subscription as part of the project. Does anyone knows how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a shared folder which has write access for the account which you will provide when the subscription is being created. Also make sure that SQL Server Agent is running before the subscription is created.

Ref: http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/07/programmatically-create-data-driven.html

OR http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36009/Programmatically-Playing-With-SSRS-Subscriptions